# how can I get the final result from a array of async ？

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm, promise

[get-video-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration) is a npm module that get the duration of video.

```js
const { getVideoDurationInSeconds } = require('get-video-duration')

// From a local path...
getVideoDurationInSeconds('video.mov').then((duration) => {
  console.log(duration)
})
```

I want to use this module to get the total duration of all videos  from an Array of video pathes.

```js
function getTotals(video_Array) {
    let total_duration = 0;
    video_Array.forEach(video => {
        getVideoDurationInSeconds(video).then(duration => {
            total_duration += duration;
            
        })
    })

}
```

The thing is `getVideoDurationInSeconds` is Asynchronous,  I can't just simply return the result.

```js
function getTotals(video_Array) {
    let total_duration = 0;
    video_Array.forEach(video => {
        getVideoDurationInSeconds(video).then(duration => {
            total_duration += duration;
        })
    })
    return total_duration;
}
```

How can I get the final result? Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `map` instead of `forEach`, create an array containing promises, and then use `promise.all`. i don't remember exactly, but `forEach` doesn't work very well with promises or async code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function which returns a promise
and then use it to calculate total duration

```
function getTotals(video_Array) {
    let video_ArrayPromises=video_Array.map(video=> 
        getVideoDurationInSeconds(video));

    return Promise.all([video_ArrayPromises]).then((values) => {
                  //Calculate TotalDuration
    return duratons.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
    });
}

getTotals(['movie1.mov','movie2.mov']).then(totalDuration => {
    //use total duration
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of `getVideoDurationInSeconds` promises with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the values returned by [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get your final total.

Additional documentation

- [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

```js
// Mock function that returns a promise.
// When it's resolved it will return a random number
// muliplied by the element passed in through the function arguments
function getVideoDurationInSeconds(el) {
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(el * rnd);
      res(el * rnd);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function getTotals(videoArray) {

  // `map` over the elements of the video array
  // and create a new array of promises
  const promises = videoArray.map(el => getVideoDurationInSeconds(el));

  // Wait until all the promises have resolved
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Then return the sum of each total in the data array
  return data.reduce((acc, c) => acc += c, 0);
}

(async function main() {
  console.log(`Total: ${await getTotals([1, 2, 3, 4])}`);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Return an array of requests and use reduce to get the total time.

```
// Array
function getTotalTime() {
    return videoList.map(async (video) => await getVideoDurationInSeconds(video));
}


// Just invoke whereever you want..
await Promise.all(getTotalTime()).then(result => {
    let totalTime = result.reduce((acc, cv) => acc + cv, 0); // 0 = default value
})
```